# JPQL (JPA) search substring

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

Im facing simple problem with searching entities by some (sub)string, which they might contain.

E.g. I have users user1, usr2, useeeer3, user4 and I will enter to search window "use" and I expect to return user1, useeer3, user4.

Im sure you know what I mean now. Is there any construction in JPA (JQPL)? It would be nice to search using WHERE somehow in named queries. Something like "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.nickname contains :substring"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `LIKE` expression. Here is a quote from the section **4.6.9 Like Expression** of the JPA 1.0 spec (JSR 220):

> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator `[NOT] LIKE` in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> string_expression [NOT] LIKE pattern_value [ESCAPE escape_character]
> ```
>
> The string_expression must have a
>   string value. The `pattern_value` is a
>   string literal or a string-valued
>   input parameter in which an underscore
>   (_) stands for any single character, a
>   percent (%) character stands for any
>   sequence of characters (including the
>   empty sequence), and all other
>   characters stand for themselves. The
>   optional escape_character is a
>   single-character string literal or a
>   character-valued input parameter
>   (i.e., `char` or `Character`) and is
>   used to escape the special meaning of
>   the underscore and percent characters
>   in `pattern_value`.
>
> Examples are:
>
> - *address.phone* LIKE ‘12%3’ is true for ‘123’ ‘12993’ and false for ‘1234’
> - *asentence.word* LIKE ‘l_se’ is true for ‘lose’ and false for ‘loose’
> - *aword.underscored* LIKE ‘\_%’ ESCAPE ‘\’ is true for ‘_foo’ and
>     false for ‘bar’
> - *address.phone* NOT LIKE ‘12%3’ is false for ‘123’ and ‘12993’ and true
>     for ‘1234’
>
> If *the value of* the
>   `string_expression` or `pattern_value`
>   is `NULL` or unknown, the value of the
>   LIKE expression is unknown. If the
>   `escape_character` is specified and is
>   `NULL`, the value of the LIKE
>   expression is unknown.